# How to make a table with separators in R-Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am not sure whether I can make a table with separator in R markdown.

This is all I can do so far.

```
| Student ID    |Exam 1|Exam 2|Exam 3|
| --------------|:----:|:-----:|:-----:|
| K             |  91 |  35 |  67 |
| L             |  45 |  40 |  80 |
| M             |  27 |  85 |  62 |
| N             |  75 |  93 |  55 |
```

What I meant by separator is that I want a line between "Student ID" and "Exam 1" columns, etc. Just like how we create a table in Microsoft word.
[image]
Thank you.

P.S I drew a line between two columns. I have not still figured out how to do that in R markdown.

Comment: Perhaps https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html

Comment: Hang on, are you asking how to do it in R or in markdown? Do you want to render an R data.frame in this way, or manually write a table in markdown?

Comment: @divibisan Hello, I want to write a table with my own information in R Markdown.

Comment: But where is the data in this table coming from? Are you typing it in yourself, as in the example you posted, and are looking for the syntax to generate a table with column borders in Markdown? Or do you have an R data.frame and you're looking for an R function to generate a visible table in your knitted report?

Comment: @divibisan yes, I am typing it itself. If you copy and paste my data above in R markdown, you can see the result yourself. Thanks!